# Java beginnings

Tags: java, cmd

I received few exercices to start apprehend the java envronment (totally newbie). below's the instructions:

> Using the same folder, create a new program that prints "Hello Geek"
>   to the screen. Well, that's easy right? But there is a catch, you are
>   not allowed to use a text editor, only the CLI. You will have to use
>   the CLI to create the file, and append the program's text to it.

I succeeded to create the new file "Hello Geek.java" with the cmd Echo.
But it seems that I cannot copy the content into this file with the basic 'Hello World" java code.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: FWIW, you probably don't want to call your file `Hello Geek.java`. You *can*, but it makes things difficult if you make the class inside it public. Your tutorials should cover this, but if your class is public, the filename has to match the class name, and class names cannot have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CON` special file can be used to read from / write to the console:

```
COPY CON HelloGeek.java
```

Type in the code.
Then, to signal the end of input, press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>